# Mapping degree 2 line bundle to a degree 1 line bundle on an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, line-bundles

Suppose I have a degree 2 line bundle $L$ on an elliptic curve $E$. Then we may
write $L = \mathcal{O}(p+q)$ for some points $p,q \in E$. If we let $\oplus$ denote the addition map on the elliptic curve $E$. Then we can map $L$ to the degree 1 line bundle $L' = \mathcal{O}(p \oplus q)$.

Is this map well defined? Does it define a morphism from the moduli space of degree 2 line bundles on $E$ to the moduli space of degree 1 line bundles on $E$?

Comment: "Then we can map..." How? What's your proposed map?

Comment: The line bundle L should correspond to some degree 2 divisor. Taking the sum of those points in the elliptic curve will give a single point. This point corresponds to a degree 1 line bundle on, which I'm calling L'

Comment: Ok, but you haven't produced a morphism of line bundles here, and in fact you can't, because twisting by $-p-q$ you get a map from $\mathcal{O}$ to a line bundle of negative degree, which can only be the zero map.

Comment: Is it well defined say not as a morphism of sheaves but instead simply between the set of degree 2 line bundles to degree 1 line bundles?

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted. Then yes; you're on the hook for proving that if $p+q\sim p'+q'$ then $p\oplus q = p'\oplus q'$ but $p+q+r\sim 3O$ iff $p\oplus q\oplus r = O$ in the group law and that does it.